# An old-style 朝?

Tags: kanji

Why does 朝 on the flag of the Asahi Shinbun Company not look like 朝?

[image]

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_the_Asahi_Shinbun_Company.svg

I looked in various places for older forms of this kanji but could not find it. Not even Halpern lists this form, although my paper edition even has "grass kanji" (草書【そうしょ】).

https://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanji/191.html?getdata=671d&search=contain&how=%E3%81%99%E3%81%B9%E3%81%A6

[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/kanji/朝/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/kanji/%E6%9C%9D/)

https://kanjitisiki.com/syogako/syogaku2/111.html

[https://jisho.org/search/朝%20%23kanji](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%9C%9D%20%23kanji)

http://wwwjdic.biz/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1MKU671d

Comment: It looks right to me.... I think that at it's root, your issue revolves around the peculiarities of different font styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asahi shimbun has its own font.

- [Asahi characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asahi_characters)

The particular 朝 is taken from 欧陽詢's 大唐宗聖観記.

The original characters look like below (from [here](https://ameblo.jp/soufu-style/entry-10989143616.html)). (新 was not used in the monument and invented.)

[image: picture]

---

- [朝日新聞ちょい解体新書-vol.01 題字編-](https://info.asahi.com/choiyomi/kaitaishinsho/01/)